# How to download any file from the content i receive in the response

Tags: reactjs, filereader

`{ "title": "Dummy File", "name": "temp_file.csv", "content": "name,role\r\n" }`
I have to download in file in the frontend using the above content in react. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could just use native js based on this example

```
// some api response
const fileContent = { "title": "Dummy File", "name": "temp_file.csv", "content": "name,role\r\n" }

// implementation
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = fileContent.name;
link.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(fileContent.content);
link.click();
```

This also assumes that file extension will always be CSV.

react example:

```
import React from 'react';

export function App(props) {

  const fileContent = { "title": "Dummy File", "name": "temp_file.csv", "content": "name,role\r\n" }

function downloadFile() {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = fileContent.name;
  link.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(fileContent.content);
  link.click();
}

  return (
    <button onClick={downloadFile}>Download File</button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Milan, this works perfectly Thanks!, but how to handle for any files like .pdf .txt etc

Comment: maybe just remove data:text/csv and file extension will be decided based on "name", so i's like `link.href = 'charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(fileContent.content);`

Comment: Yeah I have tried the same way but the downloaded pdf file is empty?? The pdf is in this format --->
%PDF-1.7\r\n%����\r\n1 0 obj\r\n<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 …470346/XRefStm 468983>>....
Not sure may be i have to convert to base64 or something else?

Comment: yeah i would say so, serving it like this in api will break things with string literals

Comment: So do we have a solution for this?